# HotKey multiple characters

Tags: autohotkey

Is it possible to define an AutoHotKey **HotKey** which require multiple characters to fire ?

Example: if I write the AHK script

^j::
Send, my test
return

The Hotkey *Control j* fires off the string "my test"

What if I wanted to require *Control jBAS* to fire off the script ...in this case the letters **BAS** following the *Control j* ? From the examples I have seen, HotKey does not seem to allow this ...I **can** accomplish this with a *HotString* ...problem with **HotString** is that you must hit Enter and then the original String is replaced with the new HotString definition.

Comment: You don't need to hit enter to trigger a hotstring, give the hotstring documentation page another read.

Comment: Thank you ...you are correct ...*enter* is not needed ...question still stands though with respect to whether it possible to define a HotKey ( versus HotString ) which requires multiple characters to fire.

Comment: You could enable a `BAS` hotstring when a `^j` hotkey is triggered. Sorry, I don't have time to write an example code for you right now, I might have time tomorrow. But see the [`Hotstring()` function](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotstring.htm), that's what you need in addition with a normal hotkey definition and misc. logic for when to turn the hotstring back off.

Comment: Thanks for idea ...I have been studying the HotKey / HotString documentation ...I will give your idea a try.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an option:

```
^j::
Input, matchVal, C L3,, BAS
if (matchVal=="BAS") {
    Send, mytest
}
Return
```

Check out https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm for further data and options.